# In GAE, file 'download' keeps downloading instead of writing content to HTML

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I'm learning to use cookies in GAE. Every time, I open localhost:8080, a file named just 'download' without any extension downloads. When I open it in notepad, it has "You've been here 0 times." So, instead of writing the content to HTML it downloads a file with the content.

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
     def get(self):
         self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'type/plain'
         visits  = self.request.cookies.get('visits', 0)
         self.response.out.write("You've been here %s times." % visits)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),], debug = True)
```

Can please anyone tell me why this is happening and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct 'Content-Type' is 'text/plain'.

```
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
```